Tensorflow CNN based fashion recognition model is repeatedly inaccurate although his so called accuracy nearing 95%
I'm trying to automate a service that is getting a picture of a client and returns the clothes he has on him, a coat for example.
I tried to code a dedicated tensorflow based module that will provide this service, and his accuracy seems fine. The model is trained based on "fashion_mnist" dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/zalando-research/fashionmnist), and is working properly with the images that the dataset provides.
However, whenever I try to upload to the model a custom image, and adjust it to it's requirements, I always get the classification "bag". I suppose it is like that because a bag is just a "basic" and depthless object, and it's easier to the AI to reroute his prediction to it.
That's the code I've been trying to run:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import cv2

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 28, 28, 1) / 255.0
test_images = test_images.reshape(test_images.shape[0], 28, 28, 1) / 255.0

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

model.save('fashion_mnist_cnn_model.h5')

model = keras.models.load_model('fashion_mnist_cnn_model.h5')

image_path = 'path_to_your_image.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
image = cv2.resize(image, (28, 28))
image = image.astype('float32') / 255.0
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=-1)

prediction = model.predict(np.array([image]))
predicted_class = np.argmax(prediction)

class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat',
               'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']
print(f'Predicted Class: {class_names[predicted_class]}')

Do you have any idea how to make him more accurate, or just how to fix the issue generally? (maybe it's something unrelated to his accuracy)
an example of a mere inaccuracy the model did is this:
The provided image: 
The classification: 

An update: the accuracy of the model this get improved after I implemented on him a background remove operation. It's still not perfect but way better.
(by the way, I'm trying to resolve this error for a day)

bad resize(). use INTER_AREA -- 28x28 is ridiculously small. don't expect miracles.

I think it's mainly the small size of the images in the training data set, which constrains you to resizing your test images and essentially downsampling and losing information.
To give you a bit of perspective, after you resize your shoe image to 28 x 28, this is what it looks like:

I could see how this would be mistaken for a bag. I tried a few other sample images, and there are cases where your trained model gets it right or at least gets close (e.g. misclassifying a dress as a shirt), so in that sense, your model is working as expected, it's just not always correct.
A machine learning model is only as good as the data it's trained on and while fashion mnist isn't a bad starting point, if you want the best results, you probably want to train on images that are larger (the DeepFashion dataset might be worth looking into). In addition, I would imagine there are lots of pretrained models for classifying clothing in images, so you don't need to reinvent the wheel by creating a model from scratch (though it is a good way to gain experience with writing ML models)

Thanks for the reference to a larger dataset, I’ve been trying to find better ones but I had no luck finding a good and reliable dataset that isn’t breaking the model in some way. About the reinventing the wheel, you’re right, I found modules that make the job easier, however, as you mentioned, I prefer to gain the experience with tensorflow related technology for further fine-tuning of AI models…
